# Grant access to Typo3 Middleware using Apache's <Location> when <Location /> is secured using Kerberos SSO

Tags: ajax, apache, typo3, single-sign-on, kerberos

I can't find a way to unlock a middleware within one of my extensions for an an external (other domain) javascript ajax-call:

```js
$.ajax({ type:"GET",
         url:'https://intranet.stadtverwaltung.loc/Personal/Personal_NeueMitarbeiterVorstellung_Kommentarabfrage?Anfangsdatum=' + jetzt.getTime() / 1000,
         success: kommentarinfoAnpassen })
```

The site is secured by:

```
 <LocationMatch "/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                AuthType Kerberos
                AuthName "Intranet of X.COM"
                KrbMethodNegotiate on
                KrbMethodK5Passwd on
                KrbAuthRealms X.COM
                KrbServiceName Any
                Require valid-user
                Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/intranetkeytab
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </LocationMatch>
```

and I'm trying to unlock the middleware (XYZ?Parameter=Whatever) by:

```
<LocationMatch "/XYZ.*">
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

If I replace "`/XYZ.*`" by "`/`" the original rule gets overwritten so that the script can access the middleware but then SSO is disabled for the entire Site, of course. When keeping the "`/XYZ.*`" the SSO works on the entire Site but also on the middleware so that the ajax-call gets rejected with 401.

Does anyone know how I can get both to work?

I already tried to solve this using: , , Require expr etc.